# Trying to append an ellipse to svg to cover points

Tags: d3.js

I have produced a scatter chart using D3.  It works okay.   Now I want to cover the points plotted with an ellipse.

I've tried to get the xOval value by looking for the max value in the dataset, same for yOval.

```
    var xOval = d3.scale.linear()
                            .domain([0,d3.max(dataset, function(d) { return d[0]; })])


        var yOval = d3.scale.linear()
                            .domain([0,d3.max(dataset, function(d) { return d[1]; })])
```

Further down in the body after the scatter is plotted I have :

```
        svg.append("ellipse")
            .attr("cx", function(d) {
                return xOval(d[0]);
            })


            .attr("cy", function(d) {
                return yOval(d[1]);
           })
           .attr("rx", 10)
           .attr("ry", 10);
```

This fails to work.

Any ideas where I'm going wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is quite difficult to do with an ellipse, as you have to make sure that everything is within the path defined by it. Here's how to do it with a circle, which should get you started.

The easiest way to do this is to use D3's polygon methods for this. In particular, you can get the centroid of the polygon defined by all points as the center of the circle. Then all you have to do is find the distance to the point that is farthest away from that and you have your radius.

The code looks something like this, assuming suitable data structures.

```
var center = d3.geom.polygon(dataset).centroid(),
r = d3.max(dataset, function(d) {
    return Math.sqrt(Math.pow(xScale(d[0]) - xScale(center[0]), 2) + Math.pow(yScale(d[1]) - yScale(center[1]), 2));
```

}) + rScale;

`rScale` here is the radius of the circles that represent a point. The radius of the covering circle needs to be extended by that to make sure that not only the center, but the entire data point circle is covered.

Complete example [here](http://jsfiddle.net/Njd9e/3/). Note that this is not optimal in the sense that there would be a smaller circle that covers all data points.

Comment: Thanks Lars.  I felt this was going to be a challenge so your idea to start with a circle is a good one.

Comment: Oh and if you're after any shape and just want to cover the points, you could use [`d3.geom.hull()`](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Hull-Geom).

Comment: Hi Lars, I've taken your suggestion on board, however, I have to apply the centerX and centerY co-ordinates to my linear scale.  I've tried to hack this to no avail.  What's the proper way to adjust for the existing scale?

Comment: For computing the distances, coordinates and radius it really doesn't matter if you take the raw data or the scaled values as long as you're consistent. If you do use the raw values, put the final ones through the scale.

Comment: Apologies but how do I push the values through the existing scale?

Comment: Just call the scale with them, e.g. `x(d[0])`, `y(d[0])`.

Comment: Lars, I've made progress.   The circle is not quite surrounding my points, can you see where I'm going a miss.   http://jsfiddle.net/Njd9e/

Comment: The problem is the radius -- it's better to scale the values for the distance function as it's affected by both scales. That doesn't really matter though because it turns out that my solution is wrong! I'll update the answer.

Comment: Thanks Lars.  I'll try and optimise this. Pythagorean theorem may come in handy.